# Flask: How to send a dictionary job from JavaScript to python

Tags: javascript, flask

I want to send a object called `accounts` which contains various details like name, email, type etc. Which can be accessed by `account.name` and so on.

I want to transfer this object from javascript to flask route.
My app.py is

```
@app.route('/completed')
def completed(variable):
    return "<h1>done {}</h1>".format(variable)
```

My javascript

```
function(accounts) {
window.location = ('{{ url_for('completed', variable='accounts') }}')
}
```

It is giving me an error

```
TypeError: completed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'variable'
```

Answer (score 0):

This jinja code

```
url_for('completed', var='foo')
```

would require this flask route

```
@app.route('/completed/<var>')
def completed(var):
```

But in this case, `foo` is just a simple string. If you want to pass a whole js object, I would use javascript to convert it to json, then use `fetch()` to POST it to the route with a json mime type, then read it in flask like so

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/completed', methods=['POST'])
def completed():
  data = request.get_json()
  return 'result is ok'
```

Edit: how to post json with fetch()

```
fetch('/completed', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify(your_js_object)
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => console.log(result));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Can you just show how to implement fetch()?